# python reference preceding items in list loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to loop through a list but at the same time make reference to the items before so i can compare.

**This is my code**:

```
list1=[(1,'a','hii'),(2,'a','byee'),(3,'a','yoo'),(4,'b','laa'),(5,'a','mehh')]
```

I want to loop through my list1 tuples such that if the second value in the tuple is the same value as the second value in the tuple before (both =='a'), then concat the third item in the tuple.

**output i want**:

```
list2=[('a','hii,byee,yoo'),('b','laa'),('a','mehh')]
```

**What i have tried**:

```
for item in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
            if item[0]==(item2[0]-1) and item[1]==item2[1]:
                     print item[2]+','+item2[2]
            elif item[0] != item2[0]-1:
                    continue
            elif item[0]==(item2[0]-1) and item[1] != item2[1]:
                     print item[2]
```

**wrong output**

```
hii,byee
byee,yoo
yoo
laa
```

From the first 2 output, it seems like the loop only looks at the preceding value but not at say 2 or more value preceding. Hence it only joined 2 words together and not 3 which it should have. The output also ends up having repeats.

How do i get around this?

Comment: Do you really only want to merge adjacent tuples? That is, the first three all get merged, but the last one, with `'mehh'`, doesn't merge with the ones from the front of the list?

Comment: it has to be adjacent and the second value of the tuple must be the same (both=='a' or some other value) and the first item of the tuple must be greater than the previous one by 1. So, it could be first 3 or first 'n' if it satisfy the requirements. Also, my list is already sorted on the first value of the tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was making this WAY harder than it needed to be

```
def combine(inval):
    outval = [inval[0]]
    for item in inval[1:]:
        if item[0] == outval[-1][0] + 1 and item[1] == outval[-1][1]:
            outval[-1] = (item[0], item[1], ",".join([outval[-1][2], item[2]]))
            continue
        outval.append(item)
    return [(item[1], item[2]) for item in outval]
```

And to test it...

```
list1 = [(1,'a','hii'),(2,'a','byee'),(3,'a','yoo'),(4,'b','laa'),(5,'a','mehh')]
list2 = [(1,'a','hii'),(3,'a','byee'),(4,'a','yoo'),(5,'b','laa'),(6,'a','mehh')]
list3 = [(1,'a','hoo'),(3,'a','byee'),(5,'a','yoo'),(6,'a','laa'),(7,'a','mehh'),(9, 'b', 'nope')]

for l in (list1, list2, list3):
    print "IN:", l
    print "OUT:", combine(l)
    print
```

OUTPUT

```
IN: [(1, 'a', 'hii'), (2, 'a', 'byee'), (3, 'a', 'yoo'), (4, 'b', 'laa'), (5, 'a', 'mehh')]
OUT: [('a', 'hii,byee,yoo'), ('b', 'laa'), ('a', 'mehh')]

IN: [(1, 'a', 'hii'), (3, 'a', 'byee'), (4, 'a', 'yoo'), (5, 'b', 'laa'), (6, 'a', 'mehh')]
OUT: [('a', 'hii'), ('a', 'byee,yoo'), ('b', 'laa'), ('a', 'mehh')]

IN: [(1, 'a', 'hoo'), (3, 'a', 'byee'), (5, 'a', 'yoo'), (6, 'a', 'laa'), (7, 'a', 'mehh'), (9, 'b', 'nope')]
OUT: [('a', 'hoo'), ('a', 'byee'), ('a', 'yoo,laa,mehh'), ('b', 'nope')]
```

This takes care of both guaranteeing sequential numbers at the 0th-index as well as equal values at the 1st-index.

Comment: I did not notice any requirement previously about the index-0 item being sequential.  That will change this a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I've updated the algorithm according to the requirements.  You can group all tuples with the same key by calling group(values, sort=True) or only group adjacent tuples with the same key by calling group(values).  This algorithm also gathers all elements after the key for the final tuple instead of only grabbing the third element.

GroupBy does this pretty well.  You can group the values by the second element in the tuple.  Then for each group, grab all of the third elements in the group and join them into one string:

```
import itertools

def keySelector(tup):
    return tup[1]

def group(values, sort=False):
    """
    Group tuples by their second element and return a list of 
    tuples (a, b) where a is the second element and b is the 
    aggregated string containing all of the remaining contents
    of the tuple.

    If sort=True, sort the tuples before grouping.  This will
    group all tuples with the same key.  Otherwise, only adjacent
    tuples wth the same key will be grouped.
    """

    if sort:
        values.sort(key=keySelector)

    grouped = itertools.groupby(values, key=keySelector)

    result = []
    for k, group in grouped:

        # For each element in the group, grab the remaining contents of the tuple
        allContents = [] 
        for tup in group:
            # Convert tuple to list, grab everything after the second item
            contents = list(tup)[2:]
            allContents.extend(contents)

        # Concatenate everything into one string
        aggregatedString = ','.join(allContents)

        # Add to results
        result.append((k, aggregatedString))

    return result

vals = [(1,'a','hii','abc','def'),
        (2,'a','byee'),
        (3,'a','yoo'),
        (4,'b','laa'),
        (5,'a','mehh','ghi','jkl')]

print(group(vals, sort=True))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'hii,abc,def,byee,yoo,mehh,ghi,jkl'), ('b', 'laa')]
```

Shortened version with list comprehensions:

```
def getGroupContents(tuples):
    return ','.join(item for tup in tuples for item in list(tup)[2:])

def group(values, sort=False):
    if sort:
        values.sort(key=keySelector)

    grouped = itertools.groupby(values, key=keySelector)
    return [(k, getGroupContents(tuples)) for k, tuples in grouped]
```

Comment: You can replace `keySelector` with [`itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: How is it that it can group by second element but not take in the last one   `(5,'a','mehh')`?

Comment: Also, how can i keep the other items in the tuple? like if my tuple had (5,'a','mehh','xyz','abc') and i want to have it all in the output?

Comment: [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) expects the `values` to be already `sorted` by the `key`: *"Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function."*  so do: `vals.sort(key=keySelector)`, or if you don't want to modify the original list, use [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted): `sorted_values = sorted(vals)`

Comment: This solution does not take into consideration the requirement that the 0th index of the tuples are sequential.